# font-face not rendering in any browser on single mac osx machine

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, firefox, font-face

Having a strange issue with a client who cannot see font-face fonts rendered in any browser on his mac. He can see them on mobile safari. All other tests we have done in various modern desktop web browsers work correctly so we have isolated the problem to a single machine.

How do I even begin troubleshooting this? We have tried having him clear cache, empty history, etc. on Safari, FF, Chrome but no luck.

**Update: this is how fonts are declared in the one main style sheet loaded from the html header:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'granadabold';
  src: url('/_ui/fonts/granadabold.eot');
  src: url('/_ui/fonts/granadabold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/_ui/fonts/granadabold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/_ui/fonts/granadabold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/_ui/fonts/granadabold.svg#granadabold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

All font files appear to be loading when I check via console. Also, as I said, it works on every other modern browser we have tried on any other machine.

Finally, we have asked hom to check out other sites with font-face active and those work for him. Stumped :(

Comment: Can he restore his machine to before the date the problem started occurring?  That would probably be the quickest way to get everything functioning normally.

Comment: are the fonts get loaded after whole website gets loaded??

Comment: @ZeroPhase he has never seen them working on this machine.

Comment: @BalramSingh see my recent update

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes works adding text-shadow: text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01); but in my case it worked for light font which wasn't rendering on my mac.